# Stripe error using Firebase Functions: Error: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments

I have written a Firebase Function that is called when a new user is created using the Firebase Authentication. It then tries to create a Stripe Customer but I get the following error in the Firebase Log:

```
createStripeCustomer
Error: You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/. at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:174:21) at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22) at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

The complete function is shown below and has been deployed to Firebase. The Stripe secret key is loaded from a config file:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {stripe} from "../../config";

export const createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: "paying.user@example.com",
        source: "src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0",
    });
    console.log("customer_Id@ ", customer.id);
});
```

Can anyone explain why I am getting the error and how I can fix the problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my own problem. The secret key was incorrectly labelled so it wasn't being loaded properly.